# What exactly is going on here? (order of limits and substitutions give different results)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

Consider this expression:

$$(-1)^{G+T+1} 2^{G-2T-2} G (G-1)(G-2) \frac{(G-T-2)!}{T!(G-2T)!}$$

Here, $G,T\in \mathbb{Z}$.

If we set $G = 2T$, it becomes

$$(-1)^{T+1}(2T-1) .$$

If we now set $T=0$, this evaluates to **one**. So far so good. Note that since $G=2T$, this obviously corresponds to $G=0$.

But if I try to set $G=0$ first, the original expression evaluates to **zero**. To make it worse, if I first set $T=0$, the original expression becomes

$$(-1)^{G+1} 2^{G-2}(G-2)$$

and it evaluates to **one half** when setting $G=0$.

I understand that taking limits in different order cannot always be done and I understand that, technically speaking, expressions of type $n!/(n-1)!$ aren't always strictly equal to $n$. Could someone shed some more light on what exactly is going on here? I'm a big boy and I don't like being confused by elementary stuff :)

Comment: Check for typos.

Comment: What does the factorial mean if $G=T=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first expression (when you first plug in $G = 2T$), the problem is a domain issue with the simplification. Substituting $G=2T$, we have $$ (-1)^{G+T+1}2^{G-2T-2}G(G-1)(G-2)\frac{(G-T-2)!}{T!(G-2T)!} = (-1)^{3T+1}2^{-2}(2T)(2T-1)(2T-2)\frac{(T-2)!}{T!}. $$

However, as you've pointed out, this last fraction $\frac{(T-2)!}{T!}$ doesn't always simplify to $\frac{1}{T(T-1)}$. In fact, it doesn't even make sense when $T -2 < 0$, without extending the definition of $!$ with something like the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Similarly, if you first set the value of $T$ to $0$, then it becomes $$ (-1)^{G+T+1}2^{G-2T-2}G(G-1)(G-2)\frac{(G-T-2)!}{T!(G-2T)!} = (-1)^{G+1}2^{G-2}G(G-1)(G-2)\frac{(G-2)!}{G!}, $$ and you run into the same problems.

Without further context on the purpose of this expression (if it's just for recreation, that's fine too!), there isn't a clear "best" way to resolve the domain issue when $G - T - 2 < 0$, $T < 0$, or $G - 2T < 0$. Here, the first is the one that is causing problems.

Comment: Basically, I have a two-variable sequence $a(G,T)$ and I'm trying to write it in closed form. There are no ambiguities for large enough Gs and Ts, but for lower ones, such as in this case, I'd like it to evaluate through the first of the methods I mentioned, i.e. it should give *one* in that particular case.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. Is $a(G, T)$ a sequence which you already have another way to evaluate? If so, just defer to the value of $a(G, T)$, and it might be fine to define multiple closed forms, for when $G < 2T$, when $G - T < 2$, when $T < 0$, etc. It might end up being a little messy if you have too many cases, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did but I wondered if there was a better way to write it... It's kinda frustrating that all the info is already there in this (admittedly ambiguous) form :)

Comment: I see..that must be frustrating! Not sure how much help I could be of there, though; perhaps you could post another question with the values of $a(G, T)$ you want to incorporate into the closed form? Just an idea.